# Unityの衝突判定でコライダーが一部離れた場合の処理を出来るようにしたい

Tags: c#, unity3d

AとBのコライダーは常時重なっている状態でAが移動を行い一部分のコライダーが離れた場合の処理を出来るようにしたいのですが可能でしょうか。OnTriggerExitは完全にコライダーが離れないと呼ばれないので使用できません。

Answer (score 0):

複数のコライダーに分けるか、被っている体積を自分で計算して条件分岐する等でしょうか。